# Creating a bash script that will create a folder for each name in the file

Tags: linux, bash

I have create a text file using ubuntu terminal named users.txt.
In this text file I have 3 user names.
I need to create a bash script that creates 3 folders with the names inside the text file.

Example names:

```
Mr A
Mr B
Mr C
```

I should have 3 folders with the above names.

Also in these folders there should also be 3 other folders named Music, Pictures, Documents and also a text file named Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Something this should do it:

```
while IFS= read -r user_name; do
     mkdir -p "${user_name}"/{Music,Pictures,Documents}
     touch "${user_name}/Welcome"
done < users.txt
```

Note that this assumes you run it from the same directory where you want these to appear and the file is in the same folder as the script.

Comment: I would replace the `< users.txt` with `< <(grep -oP '^\s*(Mr|Ms|Mrs|Miss)\.?\s*\K.*' users.txt)` for filtering out the titles... `Mr.Joe` :)

Comment: Just a recap maybe my explanation was not so accurate. Mr A , Mr b, mr c, are now named paul peter and june. So I need a bash script that takes these names in contest and creates 3 folders named paul peter and june